# Create Trigger for Insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have 2 table say A1 and A2. I want to create trigger for insert, update and delete in such way when I insert new record in table A1, same record should insert in A2,

Same should happen when I update or delete  A1 table.

Comment: there are some question (with answers!) on SO with regard to this subject. Try some of them first...

Comment: Read the [official SQL Server Books Online on triggers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx), or see [Exploring SQL Server triggers (on MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164047.aspx) for more details. Once you've read those - **try to write the trigger yourself!** If you're still stuck - come back with a **concrete question**.

Answer (score 1):

You may merge A2 with the UPDATED table of the trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trg_A1
ON dbo.A1
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS 
BEGIN

    MERGE dbo.A2 AS target
    USING (SELECT * FROM INSERTED) AS source 
    ON (target.A1_ID= source.A2_ID)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE SET Col1 = source.Col1,
                   Col2 = source.Col2,
                   .
                   .
                   .
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN   
    INSERT (Col1,Col2,Col3....)
    VALUES (source.Col1, source.Col2, source.Col3....)
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY source and target.A1_ID= source.A2_ID
    THEN DELETE     
END
```

Comment: This can work - for SQL Server **2008** and newer - if the OP is on 2005, he cannot use `MERGE` yet. ..

Comment: @marc_s So very true, but the version isn't stated, and chances are that after three newer versions he might be on one of them

Answer (score 1):

I will show you a simple way to check this in SQL Server 2000 or 2005, but in general I agree with Remus that you should break these up into separate triggers:

```
DECLARE @insert INT, @delete INT;
SELECT @insert = COUNT(*) FROM inserted;
SELECT @delete = COUNT(*) FROM deleted;
IF @insert +@delete > 0
BEGIN
    IF @insert > 0 AND @delete = 0
        -- insert
    IF @insert > 0 AND @delete > 0
        -- update
    IF @insert = 0 AND @delete > 0
        -- delete
END
```

Note that this may not be perfectly forward-compatible due to the complexity MERGE introduces in SQL Server 2008/2012.

So if you are planning to use SQL Server 2008/2012 and MERGE in the future like solution of above, then this is even more reason to split the trigger up into a trigger for each type of DML operation.